# Parse array of strings argument

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I'm trying to parse/convert an array of strings from an argument to a std::vector in my c++ addon.

Here is my code :

```
Handle<Array> array = Handle<Array>::Cast(args[4]);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < array->Length(); i++) {
  Local<Object> obj = array->CloneElementAt(i);
}
```

But whatever i do with my object (cast as string, ToString(), ...), i get coredump at execution.
Am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks for reading.

Solution :

```
Handle<Array> array = Handle<Array>::Cast(args[4]);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < array->Length(); i++) {
  Local<Value> obj = array->Get(Integer::New(i));
}
```

Comment: Is `args[4]` definitely valid?

Comment: Yep, ToString on array returns "elem1,elem2,elem3"

Comment: I found the solution (not me in fact), it's just to use Get(Integer::New(i)) instead of the CloneElementAt(i). It returns a Value that can be convert to String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use Get instead of CloneElementAt.

```
Handle<Array> array = Handle<Array>::Cast(args[4]);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < array->Length(); i++) {
  String::AsciiValue s(array->Get(Integer::New(i))->ToString());
}
```